# uninitialized local pointer error in code

Tags: c, visual-studio, pointers

Can someone identify why I get this error?

Error   C4703   potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'pw' used
Warning C6001   Using uninitialized memory 'pw'.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char string[] = "Today exam is very easy and fun", le = 'y';
    char* pStr = string, * pw;

    while (*pStr)
    {
        if (pStr == string || *(pStr - 1) == ' ')
            pw = pStr;

        if (*pStr == le && (*(pStr + 1) < 'a' || *(pStr + 1) > 'z'))
        {
            while (pw <= pStr)
                printf("%c", *pw++);
            printf(" ");
        }
        pStr++;
        while ((*pStr < 'a' || *pStr > 'z') && (*pStr < 'A' || *pStr > 'Z') && *pStr)
            pStr++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have `pw = pStr;` inside an if-statement. What happens to `pw` when the condition is not true?

Comment: @BoP it is true the first time the loop is executed.

Comment: Not related to your problem. But you might change `*(pStr + 1)` to array syntax and use the identical version `pStr[1]` to make the code more readable

Comment: The compiler just did not detect that `pw=pStr` will always be executed during first iteration. Also any human reader will take a few moments to see this. Make everyone's life (also your tomorrow's own life) easier and initialize `pw` already in the declaration: `char *pw = pStr;`

Comment: This is a false positive caused by the logic being too obscure for the code analyzer to see through.

Comment: Thank you I solved it because of your help :) Can close the question

Comment: Please create an answer. No need to close a well-asked answerable question.

Answer (score 0):

You define `pw` without an initialization here:

```
    char* pStr = string, * pw;
```

You initialize it (optionally, depending on the value pointed to by `pStr`) here:

```
    while (*pStr)
    {
        if (pStr == string || *(pStr - 1) == ' ')
            pw = pStr;
```

and you use it here, possibly uninitialized (if the above test failed all times before you entered in the code below).

```
        if (*pStr == le && (*(pStr + 1) < 'a' || *(pStr + 1) > 'z'))
        {
            while (pw <= pStr)
                printf("%c", *pw++);
```

This is a common error, just initialize it in the declaration as `NULL`

```
    char* pStr = string, * pw = NULL;
```

and later, add a check for `NULL` before the `while` loop:

```
        if (pw != NULL) {
            while (pw <= pStr)
                printf("%c", *pw++);
        }
```

You need to do, or you can get to the printf above with `pw` pointing anywhere, and get blocked in the while loop (because pw never gets bigger than pStr) or the loop never executes (because it's already bigger when you face the loop the first time.  An uninitialized local variable can have any random value you can imagine, so the compiler checks if you initialize it and warns  you in case there's some risk that the variable gets used without a proper initialization.  Good for the compiler!!!